# Adding an Image logo in Plotly pie chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to add an image in background in ring chart using Plotly but somehow the image is not displayed.
The code snipped is given below

```
plot.df <- x %>%
group_by(key) %>%
summarize(count = value)
    p <- plot_ly(plot.df, labels = key, values = count, type = "pie", hole = 0.6, textposition='null', showlegend = F,
                 marker=list(colors=c("rgb(198, 248, 253)", "skyblue"))) %>%
         layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",images = list(
           list(source = "/leaf-green.png",
                xref = "x",
                yref = "y",
                x= 1,
                y= 1,
                sizex = 1,
                sizey = 1,
                opacity = 0.8,)
         ))
    p
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removed the comma in opacity, still the image is not displayed.